Solution to this PDE?
This came up in a statistical physics problem.  A real positive density function $\rho\left(r,v\right)$ of two real positive variables r and v has this relationship to a real function z of one variable r:
$$\frac{v\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial r}}{\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial v}}=z\left(r\right)$$
$\rho\rightarrow0$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$ or $v\rightarrow\infty$, and its definite integral over both variables is finite.
From this, can we find a direct expression for $\rho$ in terms of r, v, and z(r)?
Thanks in advance.

The method of characteristics yields the solution $$\rho = f \left(Z(r) - \frac{1}{2} v^{2} \right)$$ where $Z'(r) = z(r)$ and $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. You can now apply the conditions to narrow down the form of $f$.

Typo in the above, should be $\color{red}{+} v^{2} / 2$.

$$v\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial r}-z\left(r\right)\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial v}=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dr}{v}=\frac{dv}{-z}=\frac{d\rho}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dr}{v}=\frac{dv}{-z}$ :
$$\frac12 v^2+\int z(r)dr=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{d\rho}{0}=$ not always infinite function which implies $d\rho=0$ :
$$\rho=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\rho(r,v)=F\left(\frac12 v^2+\int z(r)dr\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function. Thus the PDE has infinity many solutions.
The function $F$ has to be determined according to some initial and/or boundary conditions. The conditions specified in the wording of the question are not sufficient to determine unequivocally the function $F$.

Thanks for the explanation.  I'll have to work through this, because the method you present is completely new to me.  Your answer works if I change your - to a +.

You are right. The sign is corrected.

Note that admissible initial conditions might be a bit restricted by the initial form of the equation since we cannot have $\rho_v = 0$ for any $v\neq 0$.
